# aspxscheduler appoinment not correct viewing

Tags: asp.net, web, devexpress

i'm using aspxscheduler Devexpress tools on asp.net Webform, i set the date between 1/1/2018 to 5/1/2018
on aspxscheduler  the shadow watching only from 1/1/2018 to 4/1/2018 
i need to shading all interval including the last day (5/1/2018). anyone can help